# os.path.abspath не понял принцип работы

Tags: python, ос, path

Хочу разрезать видео используя ffmpeg tools и python. Но первому нужно передать полный путь до файла для коррекной работы. Соответсвенно использую модуль os и abspath

Структура проекта такая:

```
...
Documents
---video_divider
------venv
------video_divider.py
------videos
---------video.mp4
```

Что бы получить полный (абсолютный путь) до файла video.mp4 использую

```py
    for filename in tqdm(list_of_filenames):
        video_path = os.path.abspath(f"/{folder_name}/{filename}")
```

#### Какой результат я получаю:

`C:\videos\video.mp4`

#### Какой результат я планирую получить

`C:\ .... Documents\video_divider\videos\video.mp4`

Знаю что abspath не работает если скрипт запущен не из той же папки что и файл путь до которого я определяю, но если я в папке проекта открываю питон через консоль - все работает. В чем может быть проблема? Как можно по-другому получить этот абсолютный путь. Может быть дело в виртуальном окружении?

Comment: Слэш `/` в самом начале уберите

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слеш `/` в начале строки указывает, что абсолютный путь нужен от корня диска текущей активной директории, поэтому путь стал `C:\videos\video.mp4`

Если путь нужен от текущей папки, то просто уберите `/`:

```
    video_path = os.path.abspath(f"{folder_name}/{filename}")
```